# Specializing a base class' member function in a derived class template

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Have a look at this code:

```
struct foo {
    virtual int bleh() {
        return 42;
    }
};


template<typename T>
struct bar : public foo {

};

// ERROR
template<>
int bar<char>::bleh() {
    return 12;
}
```

I'm trying to provide a definition of `base::bleh` only for `bar<char>`, but the compiler(gcc 4.7.2) [rejects](http://ideone.com/WDs8CS) my code with the following diagnostic:

```
template-id ‘bleh<>’ for ‘int bar<char>::bleh()’ does not match any template declaration
```

It seems like `base::bleh` is somehow hidden in `bar`. I've fixed this using the following definition in `bar`:

```
template<typename T>
struct bar : public foo {
    // doesn't work
    //using foo::bleh; 

    // this works
    int bleh() {
        return foo::bleh();
    }
};
```

But I'm curious as of why this fails to compile. Why is the compiler rejecting my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your non-compiling example, you're attempting to specialize and define a function that hasn't been declared in the template definition of `bar` ... In your later example you have actually declared as well as defined the non-specialized version of the function inside the template definition of `bar`, which is why it compiles.  From what I can tell, here is the associated language in the standard concerning why the first version won't compile (14.7.3/4):

> A member function, a member function template, a member class, a
>   member enumeration, a member class template, or a static data member
>   of a class template may be explicitly specialized for a class
>   specialization that is implicitly instantiated; in this case, the
>   definition of the class template shall precede the explicit
>   specialization for the member of the class template